# UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum and writeToFile

Tags: ios, filesize, writetofile

I have a UIImage.

Option 1. I use UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.f) to get a NSData which length is about 1000000(1M). I use writeToFile:atomically: function to save the image which size is also 1M.

Option 2. I use UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum to save the image which size is about 300K.

There is so much difference. Why?

Comment: How are you finding the size of the image in step 2?

Comment: @NewEngland use iTunes to export the photo image.

Comment: Perhaps in option 2, the JPG is compressed some amount.

Comment: @rmaddy two files have same dimensions and images look the same (not blurred), but file sizes are a lot different. Is there any other API provided by Apple that can use to compress the image like that?

Comment: A JPG with just a little compression will look the same as an uncompressed JPG.

Comment: @rmaddy But two files are so much different. One is 1M and the other is 0.3M.